# Flask Uploads reading an xlsx file without saving it

Tags: python, excel, flask, xlrd

I'd like to upload an excel file in my web app, read the contents of it and display some cells. So basically I don't need to save the file as it's a waste of time.

Relevant code:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():

        f = form.xml_file.data.stream

        xml = f.read()

        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(xml)

        sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

I can't wrap my mind around this as I keep getting filetype errors no matter what I try. I'm using Flask Uploads, WTF.file and xlrd for reading the file.

Reading the file works okay if I save it previously with f.save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I solved it with

```
if form.validate_on_submit():

        # Put the file object(stream) into a var
        xls_object = form.xml_file.data.stream

        # Open it as a workbook
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=xls_object.read())
```